# How do I send keystrokes to a serial port in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I am trying to send a ctrl-x keystroke to COM2 and I ahve to code to open the port and read and write but when I tried to send `Chr(Keys.ControlKey + Keys.X)` it did not work. any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If this is interactive, the event that passes KeyChar will already pass a Char type that will be the CONTROL-X.

If your trying to generate the value, then Control-X is really just what letter is X in the alphabet. Its the 24th letter, and in ASCII that would just be 24 or 0x18.

So maybe you want a constant for it that would just be Chr(24).

Comment: So how would i send both, for example, hold control and hit X